# android saves image not correctly

Tags: android, image, kotlin, storage

I'm trying to save the image to my phone's internal storage. After trying several ways to save files, I managed to save the photo, but it does not open on the phone itself. I can find this photo in the phone's internal storage and open it (android recognizes the file as a photo since it automatically opens it in the gallery), but the photo is not displayed.

When open the photo, I see the following: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUHgJ.jpg)
In the phone, this photo takes 0 kilobytes.

> My function is to save a photo to an internal storage:

```
    fun saveImageToStorage(urlImage: String, pathTitle: String) : String{
        val dirs = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val dir = File(dirs?.absolutePath, pathTitle)
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir()
        }

        val file = File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
        val bitmap: Bitmap = downloadImage(urlImage)

        try {
            file.createNewFile()
            val imageStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, imageStream)

            val image = imageStream.toByteArray()
            Log.i("IMAGE SIZE", "${image.size}")
            imageStream.write(image)
            imageStream.flush()
            imageStream.close()

        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.message
        }

        Log.i("INFOOOOOO", file.absolutePath)
        return file.absolutePath
    }
```

> Upload an image and get a bitmap.

```
    fun downloadImage(urlImage: String): Bitmap {
        return Glide
            .with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .timeout(60_000)
            .load(urlImage)
            .fitCenter()
            .submit()
            .get()
    }
```

> I've connected the dependencies

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

> My instrumental test in which I try to perform it. It is located in "src/AndroidTest"

```
    @Test
    fun saveAdnGetPhoto(){
        val path = daoAdapter.saveImageToExternalStorage("https://www.gstatic.com/youtube/src/web/htdocs/img/tv_stack.png", "Naruto")

        Awaitility.await().atMost(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted {
            val output = daoAdapter.getPhotoFromStorage(path)
            assertEquals(true, output != null)
        }
    }
```

> Error when trying to get a photo along the saved path

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mangaua/files/Pictures/Naruto/1661511946507.jpg
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:690)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:664)
at com.example.mangaua.menu.connector.DownloadPageChapter.getPhoto(DownloadPageChapter.kt:95)
at com.example.mangaua.menu.connector.ConnectorBaseAndParse.getPhotoFromStorage(ConnectorBaseAndParse.kt:443)
at com.example.mangaua.TestDownloadAndSaveImageToExternal.saveAdnGetPhoto$lambda-0(TestDownloadAndSaveImageToExternal.kt:72)
at com.example.mangaua.TestDownloadAndSaveImageToExternal.$r8$lambda$jm-yYcWapmPfDqI53v3Npy212R8(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.mangaua.TestDownloadAndSaveImageToExternal$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
at org.awaitility.core.AssertionCondition$1.eval(AssertionCondition.java:55)
at org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter$ConditionPoller.call(ConditionAwaiter.java:201)
at org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter$ConditionPoller.call(ConditionAwaiter.java:188)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

> Function for returning photos

```
    fun getPhoto(pathImage: String) : Bitmap{
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.assets.open(pathImage))
    }
```

**Debug mode**

1. [Download photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYPBk.png)
2. [ByteArrayOutputStream to byteArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDkaC.png)
3. [Write image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1VaW.png)

thanks for your answers, I usually don't like to create themes on stack overflow due to my mistakes as I always found the answer but this time I'm trampling on one place around Sunday.

Comment: Hello, Can you try downloading a .jpg image instead of .png ? Seems like you are downloading a .png, then save it as .jpg

Comment: Also, I think you can try to use FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream.
Reference -> https://www.akshayrana.in/2020/06/how-to-save-image-to-storage-using.html

Comment: Hi @rguzman, I appreciate your help. 
1. When converting a .png image to .jpg, I never had any difficulties, it will simply make the transparent background black.
2. Replacing FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream helped me.

I'm not comfortable because the error was so simple. Could you please write a response so that I can mark it as a solution to my problem, as there is no such possibility in the comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream.